# Partial Rolled Up Aggregations in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to do a rolled up aggregation on only certain `GROUP BY` columns instead of all `GROUP BY` columns?  Instead of `SELECT a,b,SUM(c) FROM sample.data GROUP BY a,b` or `SELECT a,b,SUM(c) FROM sample.data GROUP BY ROLLUP(a,b)`, I am trying to achieve `SELECT a,b,SUM(c) FROM sample.data GROUP BY a, ROLLUP(b)`.  Is this doable in BigQuery?

The only way I can imagine doing it right now is by creating a `GROUPING` column for each column I do not wish to be rolled up and filtering those columns to only `0`.  However, when trying this I get the error `Errors encountered during job execution.  Resources exceeded during query execution.` that I do not get when not including a `ROLLUP()`.  (Same error even with `GROUP EACH BY`.)

Thoughts?

Comment: then i would guess that you first need to resolve your "resource exceeded ..." issue. which looks to me like a separate question where you should focus on presenting your actual query with just group by things. just suggestion ...

Comment: The "resource exceeded" error only appears when using "ROLLUP()"in the "GROUP BY".  Without the "ROLLUP()", the query executes normally. My actual query groups on 5 different columns and only needs to be rolled up on 1 of them.  I think that the added complexity of rolling up on 5 different columns (instead of just 1) is causing the error which is why I was wondering if there was way to roll up on only one column

Comment: got it  - i was confused by your statement - "(Same error even with GROUP EACH BY.)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think sysntax like `GROUP BY a, ROLLUP(b)` is available! It is not!
Just as a workaround for your case I would propose below mimicing of such syntax

So, assuming you have table `sample.data` with `a, b, c, d` and you need to mimic

```
SELECT a, b, c, SUM(d) as s 
FROM table 
GROUP BY a, b, ROLLUP(c)
```

Below is ROLLUP-less *"version"* of it :

```
SELECT a, b, c, s 
FROM (
  SELECT a, b, c, SUM(d) AS s 
  FROM sample.data
  GROUP BY a, b, c
  ), (
  SELECT a, b, NULL AS c, SUM(s) AS s
  FROM (
    SELECT a, b, c, SUM(d) AS s 
    FROM sample.data
    GROUP BY a, b, c
  ) 
  GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
)
ORDER BY a, b, c
```

Answer (score 1):

MS SQL support groups like these:

```
GROUP BY a, ROLLUP(b, c)
GROUP BY ROLLUP(a, b), ROLLUP(c, d)
```

See article https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx

Google BQ still doesn't support.

You can use **HAVING** clause, like this:

```
SELECT a,b,SUM(c) FROM sample.data GROUP BY ROLLUP(a,b) 
HAVING a is not null
```

OR

```
SELECT a,b,SUM(c) FROM sample.data GROUP BY ROLLUP(a,b) 
HAVING GROUPING(a)=0
```

This solution doesn't solve problem with **Error: Resources exceeded during query execution.**

I suppose, that full support of rollup, cube and grouping sets is a good feature for future BQ releases.

Answer (score 1):

RollUp is on Bigquery available in Legacy SQL (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#groupby) which is not exactly great if you also need to use some features from Standard SQL.